# Google Cloud Task Queue RateLimits config being ignored

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

We are creating a Google Cloud Tasks queue (v2beta3) with the rate limit config set however this rate limit config is being ignored and instead it uses Googles defaults:

```
cloud_tasks_res = await tasksClient.createQueue({
  parent: `projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/LOCATION`,
  queue: {
    name: `projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/LOCATION/queues/myqueue`,
    rateLimits: {
      maxTasksDispatchedPerSecond: 100,
      maxConcurrentTasks: 50
    },
    retryConfig: { 
      maxAttempts: 150,
      maxRetryDuration: { seconds: 0, nanos: 0 },
      minBackoff: { seconds: 15, nanos: 0 },
      maxBackoff: {  seconds: 43200, nanos: 0 },
      maxDoublings: 13
    }
  }
});
```

With `cloud_tasks_res` returning:

```
[
  {
    name: `projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/LOCATION/queues/myqueue`,
    purgeTime: null,
    rateLimits: { 
      maxBurstSize: 100, 
      maxConcurrentDispatches: 1000, 
      maxDispatchesPerSecond: 500 
    },
    retryConfig: {
      maxAttempts: 150,
      maxBackoff: { nanos: 0, seconds: "43200" },
      maxDoublings: 13,
      maxRetryDuration: null,
      minBackoff: { nanos: 0, seconds: "15" }
    },
    stackdriverLoggingConfig: null,
    state: "RUNNING"
  },
  undefined,
  undefined
]
```

As per the documentation how we've done it looks correct: 
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/v2beta3.CloudTasksClient.html#createQueue
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.html#.RateLimits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the fields specified correctly:

`maxTasksDispatchedPerSecond` needs to be `maxDispatchesPerSecond`
`maxConcurrentTasks` needs to be `maxConcurrentDispatches`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! So turns out that if you start off on th2 v2beta3 documentation page and then click a link it takes you to the v2beta2 page which uses different variable names... (in the links above I had corrected it to beta3 and not considered that it had taken me to the wrong page!)

Comment: It is only the left navigation links that change you to the wrong version. For reference I've created a issue tracker to correct this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140290147

Comment: Thank you for adding the issue. I'm sorry about the confusion.